# Find out where a SQL table is stored on a drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have some huge tables in a DB. These are divided over multiple file groups. I checked the location of these file groups by right-clicking and viewing the database properties. But some of these file groups are stored over multiple drives.

Basically I have a table ABC stored over file group ARCHIVE which is stored on D:\Archive, E:\Archive, H:\Archive and so on. Is there a way I can find out where ABC is stored on the drive?

I need this info since one of the drives is getting full and I'm not sure which unnecessary tables are stored on it so I can get rid of them. I'm using SSMS 2008.

Comment: Why don't you just remove ***all*** unnecessary tables, and then see where you stand? Not that that will shrink the files but it will give you a better idea of which files *can* be altered.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have deleted the really unnecessary tables but they were pretty small. The remaining tables are somewhat important but they can be moved to a different drive since they are not used that much. But I'm not sure where these somewhat important tables are stored and I wanted to find that out before moving stuff around by trial and error.

Comment: Duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/42678

Comment: That's the thing - a table that belongs to a filegroup will be distributed across all the files in the filegroup. So finding out where "a table" lives in such case is pretty useless - are you really going to move the entire table, from all of the files in that filegroup, to a different filegroup, when probably only one of the files is a problem? In which case you can perform an `EMPTYFILE` which will move the data in *all* tables in that problematic file to the other files in that filegroup.

Comment: thanks. I'll dig in more and take a look at the EMPTYFILE command.

Comment: You might want to look at the standard reports under the right click in the object browser, top tables by space.  This will allow you to find those tables that have zero records.  But Shiva/Aaron are right about tables on multiple files.  EMPTYFILE  moves all tables off the file group.  Another solution is to rebuild that one table onto a different file group, again, this is a risk when the file size gets large.  Take a good backup before starting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Tables can exist across multiple datafiles in a filegroup. So I'm not sure you can actually find out where the table is stored on a drive, cause it could be stored in parts across several data files.

Source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42680

> An object in a filegroup will use all datafiles in the filegroup. Any
>   table in FG1 resides equally on Datafile1, Datafile2 and Datafile3. If
>   you need to control placement you need to create distinct filegroups.
>   To remove a file from a file group use `DBCC SHRINKFILE EMPTYFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the little utility stored procedure I wrote to get detailed database info.

http://craftydba.com/?p=3905

It basically does an sp_heldb on every database.  It uses a cursor on a limited number of databases.

A ton of information.  If you just want the file information, change the call around to

```
select * from sys.dastabase_files
```

Optionally, write the information to a temp table like my usp_who2 utility.

http://craftydba.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/usp-who2.txt

Then you can slice and dice the data with SELECT statements.

PS:  Aaron has a good suggestion, clean house first before running this.